# how much bandwidth does exchange server 2003 outlook web access need?

Tags: exchange-2003, bandwidth, outlook-web-app

How much bandwidth does an Outlook <-> Exchange https connection use?

Comment: We could measure you some string too if you like :)
Do you mean outlook to exchange as you mention web-access in the subject, they're different things - and I'm sure you're aware that message quantity and complexity will massively affect any figures anyone give you right?

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to answer this question. It depends on the number of users, how active they are, how much they are downloading attachments, etc etc.

Comment: Yes, its impossible to answer *exactly*.  But if someone admins OWA at a big organization, they might be able to tell you the average of their users for their setup, which could be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from usage sending / receiving email usage, because using http-rpc is a Cached mode of operation at the base level it is more bandwidth efficient than a non-cached mode of operation.  In cached mode the clients check in with the server only periodically thus, if they are not checking in with the server they are not using bandwidth.  If you are converting existing users, use some performance counters to profile your current use over a period of several 'typical' days - this is the only way to guestimate a specific environment.

[Also maybe useful(last comment)](http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/exchange-server-design/t-rpc-over-http-bandwidth-requirement-315538.html).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it depends on the user and what they are doing.  But this [Microsoft White Paper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/6/4/a64f834b-66fa-4221-934f-2bdf4c6cc83f/client_network_traffic_with_exchange_2003_v1.1.doc) has extensive details about how much bandwidth is used during various web operations.  You can use these statics based on what version of OWA (Premium or Basic) they are using, guess what an average user would do, and then multiply it.  *This is going to be a very rough estimate.*

You didn't say why you want to know, are you trying to plan out how wide of a link to get?  If that is the case, make sure you get more then you think you need.  You will have to think about how many people will be using this at *peak* times.